# How to loop inside loop in list with raster?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, foreach, r-raster

I have the spatial dataset below. It is composed by points in space that constitute tracks made by each ID (e.g. individual animal) and SUB-IDS (route simulations for invidual animal).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(data.table)

ids <- c("844", "844", "844", "844", "844","844", "844", "844", "844", "844",
        "844", "844", "845", "845", "845", "845", "845","845", "845", "845", 
        "845","845", "845", "845")
sub_ids <- c("2017_844_1", "2017_844_1", "2017_844_1", "2017_844_1", "2017_844_2",
        "2017_844_2", "2017_844_2", "2017_844_2", "2017_844_3", "2017_844_3",
        "2017_844_3", "2017_844_3", "2017_845_1", "2017_845_1", "2017_845_1", 
        "2017_845_1", "2017_845_2","2017_845_2", "2017_845_2", "2017_845_2", 
        "2017_845_3","2017_845_3", "2017_845_3", "2017_845_3")
lat <- c(-30.6456, -29.5648, -27.6667, -31.5587, -30.6934, -29.3147, -23.0538, 
         -26.5877, -26.6923, -23.40865, -23.1143, -23.28331, -31.6456, -24.5648, 
         -27.6867, -31.4587, -30.6784, -28.3447, -23.0466, -27.5877, -26.8524, 
         -23.8855, -24.1143, -23.5874)
long <- c(-50.4879, -49.8715, -51.8716, -50.4456, -50.9842, -51.9787, -41.2343, 
          -40.2859, -40.19599, -41.64302, -41.58042, -41.55057, -50.4576, -48.8715, 
          -51.4566, -51.4456, -50.4477, -50.9937, -41.4789, -41.3859, -40.2536, 
          -41.6502, -40.5442, -41.4057)
df <- tibble(ids, sub_ids, lat, long)


#converting ​to sf
df.sf <- df %>% 
 ​sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)
```

I also have a sf grid created from points:

```
#creating grid
xy <- sf::st_coordinates(df.sf)

grid = sf::st_make_grid(sf::st_bbox(df.sf),
                       ​cellsize = .1, square = FALSE) %>%
 ​sf::st_as_sf() %>%
 ​dplyr::mutate(cell = 1:nrow(.))
```

**loop1 inside mylist[[j]]:** The idea is to generate a rasterlayer for each SUB ID containing number of points per cell and add these layers in rasterbrick object, calculate the rasterbrick average and resulting in 1 rasterlayer .

**loop2 inside mylist:** Doing this process inside each list element, creating 1 rasterlayer to each ID, and again add the resulting rasterlayers into a rasterbrick to calculate the average and get a single rasterlayer.

```
#creating rasters objects
r <- raster::raster(grid, res=0.1)
rr <- raster::brick(r)
rr2 <- raster::brick(r)   

df.sf$ids <- as.factor(df.sf$ids)
mylist <- split(df.sf, df.sf$ids) #list to each ID

#looping
   
 for(j in 1:length(unique(mylist))){
      
for(i in 1:length(unique(mylist[[j]]$sub_ids))) {
    
   output1[j]<- stackApply(addLayer(rr,rasterize(subset(mylist[[j]], 
                        sub_ids == unique(mylist[[j]]$sub_ids)[i]), 
                                 y = r, 
                                 field = 1, 
                                 background = 0,
                                 fun="count")), indices =  rep(1,nlayers(rr)), 
                   fun = "mean", na.rm = T)+1 
    
output2 <- stackApply(addLayer(rr2, output1[j]), indices =  rep(1,nlayers(rr2)), 
                fun = "mean", na.rm = T) }}
```

I tried with for() as shown above but this error is occurring:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  erro na avaliação do argumento 'x' na seleção do método para a função 'nlayers': 'operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types'
In addition: Warning message:
In x@data@values[i] <- value :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

**EDIT: process of each subset by one ID**

```
############## ID 844

#subset one ID
id.844 <- subset(df.sf,df.sf$ids=="844")
id.844$sub_ids <- as.factor(id.844$sub_ids)

#subset SUB IDS
id.844.1 <- subset(id.844, id.844$sub_ids=="2017_844_1")
id.844.2 <- subset(id.844, id.844$sub_ids=="2017_844_2")
id.844.3 <- subset(id.844, id.844$sub_ids=="2017_844_3")

#SUB ID 1
output1 <- raster::rasterize(x = id.844.1, 
                             y = r, 
                             field = 1, 
                             background = 0,
                             fun="count")
#SUB ID 2
output2 <- raster::rasterize(x = id.844.2, 
                             y = r, 
                             field = 1, 
                             background = 0,
                             fun="count")
#SUB ID 3 
output3 <- raster::rasterize(x = id.844.3, 
                             y = r, 
                             field = 1, 
                             background = 0,
                             fun="count")

#joining rasters SUB IDS
rasterbrick<- raster::brick(output1, output2, output3)

#mean ID 1
result.id1 <- raster::stackApply(rasterbrick, 
                                 indices =  rep(1,nlayers(rasterbrick)), 
                                 fun = "mean", na.rm = T)
```

Comment: Can you show the long way of doing what you need without looping? For example, show how to process *one* subset by id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
build_raster_mean <- function(sub_df) {
  rasterize_list <- by(
    sub_df, 
    sub_df$sub_ids,
    function(sub_id_df) raster::rasterize(
      x = sub_id_df, y = r, field=1, background = 0, fun='count'
    )
  )
  
  rasterize_list2 <- unlist(rasterize_list, recursive=F)
  
  raster_brick <- raster::writeRaster(brick(rasterize_list2), 
                              names(rasterize_list2), bylayer=TRUE,
                              overwrite=TRUE)
  
  raster_mean <- raster::stackApply(
    raster_brick, 
    indices = rep(1,nlayers(raster_brick)), 
    fun = "mean", 
    na.rm = TRUE
  )
}

#loop in list 
raster_mean_list <- purrr::map(mylist, build_raster_mean)

#new raster brick with IDS mean
raster_mean_brick <- raster::writeRaster(brick(raster_mean_list), 
                                 names(raster_mean_list), bylayer=TRUE,
                                 overwrite=TRUE)
#rasterlayer with average final
raster_mean_final <- raster::stackApply(raster_mean_brick , 
                            indices = rep(1,nlayers(raster_mean_brick)), 
                            fun = "mean", 
                            na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider generalizing your process with a user-defined function, then pass into the method subsets with a nested `by`, the object_oriented wrapper to `tapply` where you split a data frame by factor(s) then pass subsets into a function and largely synonymous to `split`+`lapply`. Use `do.call` to combine raster bricks.

```r
build_raster_mean <- function(sub_df) {
    rasterize_list <- by(
        sub_df, 
        sub_df$sub_ids,
        function(sub_id_df) raster::rasterize(
            x = sub_id_df, y = r, field = 1, background = 0, fun="count"
        ),
        simplify = FALSE
    ) |> `attributes<-`(NULL)

    raster_brick <- do.call(raster::brick, rasterize_list)
    
    raster_mean <- raster::stackApply(
        raster_brick, 
        indices = rep(1,nlayers(raster_brick)), 
        fun = "mean", 
        na.rm = TRUE
    )
}

raster_mean_list <- by(
    df.sf, df.sf$ids, build_raster_mean, simplify=FALSE
)
```

Comment: This is perfect, will very help me. Thank you so much. But raster functions are apparently not accepting this list format that results from the by() function, I tried replacing do.call() with this example https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130707/how-to-write-every-raster-from-a-list-of-rasters but the problem seems to be with signature '"by"'' from rasterize_list, I don't understand why. Is there an alternative?

Comment: link example: raster_brick <- writeRaster(brick(list), names(list), bylayer=TRUE, format='GTiff')

Comment: What error do you receive? See edit using `simplify=FALSE` in each [**`by`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/by) call. If needed, run `unclass()` on the *rasterize_list* inside `do.call`.

Comment: simplify=FALSE does not resolve:

Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
   error evaluating argument 'x' in method selection for function 'writeRaster': 'unable to find an inherited method for function 'brick' for signature '"by"'''

Comment: The unlist() function solved my problem, thank you. The do.call() function creates one 'rasterbrick' for each SUB ID instead of merging them all into one. The writeRaster() function solves this problem with the argument "bylayer=T" but it doesn't accept list in 'by' format as shown in the error above. I replaced do.call() with this and it worked:

rasterize_list2 <- unlist(rasterize_list, recursive=F)
   raster_brick <- writeRaster(brick(rasterize_list2),
                               names(rasterize_list2), bylayer=TRUE)

Comment: Hmmmm....`do.call(raster::brick, mylist)` is equivalent to long form of: `raster::brick(mylist[[1]], mylist[[2]], mylist[[3]], ...)`. Can you try one more time without the `writeRaster` workaround aligned to your posted long form version? Unless `raster::brick(output1, output2, output3)` does not work. I added a line to remove attributes from return of `by` object.

Comment: Like this the function() worked perfectly. But then the final looping doesn't work like before. ```raster_mean_list <- by( df.sf, df.sf$ids, build_raster_mean, simplify=FALSE)```
I tried that too and got the same error: ```raster_mean_list <- map(mylist, build_raster_mean)``` ERRO: 

```Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) :
unable to find an inherited method for function 'brick' for signature '"NULL"'```

Comment: Did you run first `by` call with ```|> `attributes<-`(NULL)``` and pass that result into `do.call`? See my [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71894810/revisions). This should return only a `list` of `rasterize` objects that should work for `raster::brick`.

Comment: Yes, when I run by call, it works perfectly. The 'raster_mean' object returns exactly the final raster I need, but the loop returns this error. Maybe you're right, there might be some problem with the brick() function in this context. I'm not great expert in raster analyzes.

Comment: I can't send chat, so I added in the edit the way I managed to loop because it doesn't fit here

Comment: Understood. Glad to help. By the way, You can answer your own question and accept it! Consider moving the edit to an answer.